# REST api 404 on mapping

Tags: java, rest, jakarta-ee, glassfish, jersey-2.0

I am trying to create a rest api using jersey on glassfish 4 server.
Currently i am getting error 404 whenever I go to my mapping:

http://localhost:8080/LibraryRestTest/api/books

Sadly i get 0 errors on my glassfish console log. I have also tried manually deploying my war on glassfish admin console to result in the same error.

Is there something I haven't yet implemented ?

---

### All files i have created in my project :

### glassfish-web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE glassfish-web-app PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Servlet 3.0//EN" "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-web-app_3_0-1.dtd">
<glassfish-web-app>
    <context-root>/LibraryRestTest</context-root>
</glassfish-web-app>
```

### web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">

     <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer
        </servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>
                jersey.config.server.provider.packages
            </param-name>
            <param-value>
                com.koen.library
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

### pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.koen</groupId>
    <artifactId>LibraryRestTest</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <webXml>WebContent\WEB-INF\web.xml</webXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <properties>
        <jersey.version>2.22</jersey.version>
        <parser.version>2.22</parser.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.koen.library</groupId>
            <artifactId>libraryJPA</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Jersey -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>${parser.version}</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

### BookResource.java

```
package com.koen.library;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;

import com.koen.library.pojo.Book;



@Path("books")
public class BookResource {

    @GET
    @Produces("application/json")
    public ArrayList<Book> getAll(){
        return new ArrayList<Book>(){{add(new Book(6, "The Brothers Karamazov", "Fyodor Dostoevsky"));}};
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/{id}")
    public Book getById(@PathParam ("id") int id){

        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: You wouldn't be having this problem if you'd used spring-boot and spring-rest, and any problems you do have would be a lot easier to diagnose. If you have any scope to change, do so immediately.

Comment: what do you expect from you r request

Comment: a json of the list with one book entry, see `BookResource`

Comment: even if it gives me nothing its fine. but 404 ?

Comment: are you check the port8080

Comment: my glassfish is up and running at localhost:8080

Answer (score 1):

Instead of mapping a jersey servlet in `web.xml`, you could configure your REST endpoint using Java code using standard Java EE 7 API ([Application](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Application.html) and [@ApplicaionPath](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/ApplicationPath.html):

```
@ApplicationPath("api")
public class ApplicationConfig extends Application {
}
```

This will automatically attach all resources annotated with `@Path` to the `api` suffix.
If you do not want all resources to map to this suffix, you may list each class in particular, if you override `getClasses()` method:

```
@ApplicationPath("api")
public class ApplicationConfig extends Application {
    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        return Arrays.asList(com.koen.library.BookResource.class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The fix to my problem was:

```
<param-value>true</param-value>
```

I had to add that line in my web.xml.
Now i don't get any 404 error on my mapping.

---

### Web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">

     <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer
        </servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>
                jersey.config.server.provider.packages
            </param-name>
            <param-value>
                com.koen.library
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: That makes absolutely no sense. Did you just make this up, or did you find this solution somewhere? If the latter, please link to source.

Comment: I was looking at my web.xml with eclipse's gui tool. I know this is weird but then again, why did it so the trick?